# Does gradient exist, when we know the directional derivative of function f(x, y)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

This is the full question I got.

> There are two unit vectors $u$ and $v$. The two vectors are not parallel. We assume that we know the directional derivatives of function $f(x, y)$ at point $(x_0, y_0)$ heading to the direction of $u$ and $v$. At this point $(x_0, y_0)$, is it possible to find the gradient $\nabla f$? If so prove it. If not, find a counterexample.

I think the answer to this question is "yes". Because the directional derivative can be written as
$$ \tag{*}
D_u f(x_0, y_0) = \nabla f(x_0, y_0) \cdot u
$$
And I think the proof of (*) will justify my answer. Am I on the right track? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The proof of the formula $D_u f(x_0,y_0)=\nabla  f(x_0,y_0) \cdot u$ uses the hypothesis that $\nabla f(x_0,y_0)$ exists. So your argument is circular.

Comment: The question assumes that Dᵤf(x₀,y₀) and Dᵥf(x₀,y₀) exist. Then is it obvious that gradient(∇f) exists too?

Comment: @Hiesun Under the assumption from the problem that $u$ and $v$ are not parallel, whether $\nabla f$ is guaranteed to exist may depend on your textbook.